# Download MODIS hdf using the MODIS package

Tags: r, https, satellite, r-modis

I am trying to download MODIS data from the LAADS and LPDAAC server using the MODIS-package. I am quite inexperienced with these kind of functions, so any help is appreciated!

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
    library(MODIS)
    MODISoptions()
    getProduct("MOD11C3")
    getCollection("MOD11C3")
     b1 <- getHdf(product = "MOD11C3", begin = "2007.07.01", end="2007.12.31")
```

As soon as I am trying to get the hdf files from the server with the getHdf function, I get the following error:

```
    Updating collections from LPDAAC for platform: Terra 
    Error in if (FtpDayDirs[1] == FALSE) { : 
    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: does `download.file('ftp://ladsftp.nascom.nasa.gov/allData/6/MOD11C3/2007/182/MOD11C3.A2007182.006.2015321160040.hdf', tempfile())` do anything? Perhaps you can't make FTP connections at all?

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I get an error saying
        160040.hdf': status was '550 Requested action not taken; file unavailable'

So maybe the issue is on my side after all ?

Comment: Possibly your network requires a proxy for FTP transfer... Suggest you contact your local experts...